# Sort fields in MySQL table by sum of the columns

Tags: mysql

I have data in a table with the fields comprising of the names of individuals, and the rows comprising of data related to their contribution to a certain task. For example:

[image]

Person 1's sum is 13, while person 2's sum is 25.  I would like the results to present the columns in the Person 2, Person 1 order.

I am looking to sort the query results to rearrange table fields (the names of the people) in order of the sums of each person (column sum)

Comment: When you say "column sum", to what exactly do you refer?

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY columnA + columnB + columnC` to sort by the sum of different fields.

Comment: Please don't ask two different things in one question. One person may be able to answer question 1, and someone else may be able to answer question 2. You need to ask a single question so that someone can answer it completely and you'll accept that answer.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Please edit the question to make it clearer, don't put the clarifications in comments. It would be best if you showed an example of the input table and the desired results.

Comment: Sorting normally reorders **rows**, not **columns**.

Comment: @Barmar I believe you misunderstood the intent.  I don't want to sort the rows, I want to sort the columns.

Comment: Please show that in the question. And don't use images, use plain text tables.

Comment: @Barmar I know sorting is usually done on rows.  I am here for a novel solution to an irregular problem.

Comment: Normalise your schema.

Comment: @Strawberry my schema is normalized - this was just a simple example explaining what I want as far as organization of the results..  Every entry has a unique primary key to identify the row.

Comment: We can only answer the question that is asked. If you have a normalised schema, then by all means present it to us, amending your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `GREATEST` and `LEAST` functions to reorder the values. And you can calculate the sums of each original column in a subquery.

```
SELECT IF(GREATEST(sum1, sum2) = sum1, 'Person1', 'Person2') as HigherName,
       GREATEST(sum1, sum2) as val1 AS HigherVal,
       IF(LEAST(sum1, sum2) = sum1, 'Person1', 'Person2') AS LowerName,
       LEAST(sum1, sum2) as LowerVal
FROM (SELECT SUM(Person1) AS sum1, SUM(Person2) AS sum2
      FROM YourTable) AS x
```

This will produce a result like:

```
HigherName  HigherVal   LowerName   LowerVal
Person2     25          Person1     13
```

Comment: Yep, I'm having that Donald Sutherland Body Snatchers moment again.